# Error Boundary in React 18 not working when child component has an error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend

I have an MFE app that is consuming a component from another project. This is my error boundary component:

```
export default class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.log(error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    // If I comment this line out, it doesn't render anything but it doesn't crash either
    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

As mentioned in the comment above, when I have a component that is throwing an error, I get this error:

```
Script error.
    at handleError (webpack://home/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js?:252:58)
    at eval (webpack://home/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js?:271:7)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (webpack://pdp/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack://pdp/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack://pdp/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:27446:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack://pdp/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:26552:12)
    at workLoopSync (webpack://pdp/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:26461:5)
    at renderRootSync (webpack://pdp/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:26429:7)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (webpack://pdp/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:26080:20)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (webpack://pdp/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:12042:22)
```

I looked at the webpack config file for both projects, and the look OK, but I'm not sure what else the problem could be.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Where is the error boundary being used? If it's in the parent app, wrapping an MFE component, then the error will probably hit any error boundaries in that MFE project first (like the one used by `webpack-dev-server` to display the error screen)

Comment: @DBS - I'm told the project I'm getting the component from has no error boundaries. I'm using the Error Boundary in the app I'm working on, which is consuming the MFE from another project (I'm a bit new to MFE's so I hope this made sense.)